# JS onClick not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

Just don't know why this piece of code is not working: (onClick not working, click() is working (using console))

```
function click(ID)
{

    if(cost[ID] <= currency[costID[ID]])
    {

        currency[costID[ID]] -= cost[ID];
        currency[ID] += buyamout[ID];

        document.getElementById(x[costID[ID]]).innerHTML = "<center>"+(Math.round(notyfication(currency[costID[ID]])*100)/100)+not+"</center>";
        document.getElementById(x[gainID[ID]]).innerHTML = "<center>"+(Math.round(notyfication(currency[gainID[ID]])*100)/100)+not+"</center>";

    }

}


...'<button onClick="click('+i+');">'+button+x[i]+'</button>'
```

this gives output `<button onClick="click(0);">Make DNA</button>`
and after clicking button nothing happens.

Comment: What is that code generating the button? Is that JavaScript as well?

Comment: did u check console... what error u r getting ?

Comment: you may try `onclick=` instead of `onClick=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a namespace conflict with your `click`. Use another name like `button_click` below

```js
var i = 0;
var button = "Make ";
var x = [['DNA']]
document.writeln('<button onclick="button_click('+i+');" >'+(button+x[i])+'</button>');

function button_click(ID) { // notice the function name change
  alert(ID);
}
```

Code below not working:

```js
var i = 0;
var button = "Make ";
var x = [['DNA']]
document.writeln('<button onclick="click('+i+');" >'+(button+x[i])+'</button>');

function click(ID) { // the function name click may have been used already
  alert(ID);
}
```

indeed `onclick="click('+i+');"` executes the javaScript code between the double brackets: `click('+i+');`: it calls the javaScript `click()` function, but this does not work if you declare `function click()` and someone else did that elsewhere in javaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

if onClick is not working you can also use addEventListener will do the same job.
for e.g.

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() { /* do stuff here*/ }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you must do the following.

Change:

```
onClick="click(0)"
```

To:

```
onclick="click(0)"
```

That will most probably fix your problem.